# How to deal with columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do something with column data which is a list. like:

inputs:

```
col-A

[{'name':'1','age':'12'}, {'name':'2','age':'12'}]

[{'name':'3','age':'18'}, {'name':'7','age':'15'}]
```

....

outputs:

```
col-A

[{'1-age':'12'}, {'2-age':'12'}]

[{'3-age':'18'}, {'7-age':'15'}]
```

....

My code is:

```
def deal(dict_col, prefix_key):
    key_value = dict_col[prefix_key]+'-'
    dict_col.pop(prefix_key, None)
    items = copy.deepcopy(dict_col)
    for key, value in items.items():
        dict_col[key_value+key] = dict_col.pop(key)
    return dict_col  

prefix = "name"
[[deal(sub_item, prefix) for sub_item in item] for item in df[col-A]]
```

Some items will be processed multiple times. 
Because the return value of deal method will be swapped to item in real time?

For example:

For deal method we

input:

```
{'name':'1','age':'12'}
```

output:

```
{'1-age':'12'}
```

Then the next input may be `{'1-age':'12'}` , and now we have no name or age to deal with.

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `deal` function?

Comment: I have added deal method to the question. @jezrael

Comment: not sure how geenral solution is necessary, do you ned processing only `age` with `name` ?

Comment: I only see dictionaries here. Where are you dealing with a dataframe?

Comment: The sub_item dict has some other keys(may be missed sometime). I want to deal with every key with name, not only age.  My test data has only age and name.This error happened when running the test data. @jezrael

Comment: Deal method has been added to the question. @DeepSpace

Comment: @Anuo - whats happen if no value `prefix_key` in some dict ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pandas `apply` method for it here some code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col-A' : [[{'name' : '1', 'age': '12'}, {'name' : '2', 'age': '12'}],[{'name' : '3', 'age': '18'},{'name' : '7', 'age': '15'}]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def deal(row, prefix):
    out_list = []
    for sub_dict in row:
        out_dict = {}
        out_str = sub_dict.get(prefix) + '-'
        for k,v in sub_dict.items():
            out_dict[out_str + k] = v
        out_list.append(out_dict)
    return out_list
prefix = 'name'
df['col-A'] = df['col-A'].apply(lambda x : deal(x, prefix))

print(df)
```

You could push some of the code in a one-liner if you like that more:

```
def deal(row, prefix):
    out_list = []
    for sub_dict in row:
        out_dict = dict((sub_dict[prefix] + '-' + k , sub_dict[k]) for k in sub_dict.keys() if k != prefix)
        out_list.append(out_dict)
    return out_list
prefix = 'name'
df['col-A'] = df['col-A'].apply(lambda x : deal(x, prefix)
```

Just for the fun of it you could even bring it down to one single line (not recommended due to poor readability:

```
prefix = "name"
df['col-A'] = df['col-A'].apply(lambda row : [dict((sub_dict[prefix] + '-' + k , sub_dict[k]) for k in sub_dict.keys() if k != prefix) for sub_dict in row])
```

Comment: I modify ```out_str = sub_dict.pop(prefix) + '-'``` to ```out_str = sub_dict.get(prefix) + '-'``` . Success!  The list comprehension and apply lambda  are copy method ,not deep copy. I think it is the reason. Thank you. @LeoE

Comment: Just wondering, since everybody wants to change the `pop` to a `get`: This does not result in the right output, right?

Comment: Got keyerror when using pop. Not to change sub_dict makes the right result.

Comment: I don't this irritates me, it works perfectly for me... if you don't pop it you will have things like `{'1-name' : '1'} in there, don't you? Are you using python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: 3.x.  You are right. will get {'1-name' : '1'} . I chose  ```if !=prefix```  which will not change sub dict. @LeoE

Comment: If it works I'm happy, I'm just wondering, why it works for me using `pop`

Comment: It is running ok when test data is small. I got error when added more data to test the code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `.get` function for select with default value if not exist key in dict:

```
def deal(dict_col, prefix_key):
    key_value = dict_col.get(prefix_key, 'not_exist')+'-'
    dict_col.pop(prefix_key, None)
    items = copy.deepcopy(dict_col)
    for key, value in items.items():
        dict_col[key_value+key] = dict_col.pop(key)
    return dict_col
```

Comment: Get a lot of items 'not_exist-name-age': age_value,  like: 'not_exist-1-age': 12.

Comment: ```def deal(dict_col, prefix_key):
    print(dict_col) # {'not_exist-name-age': age_value} 
    key_value = dict_col.get(prefix_key, 'not_exist')+'-'
    ...
    return dict_col```

Comment: @Anuo - yop, question is whats happen if no value `name` like `[{'aa':'1','age':'12'}, {'d':'2','age':'12'}, {'name':'2','age':'12'}]]` for first and second dict ?

Comment: Test data has only name and age which has been checked.  Maybe we can not change item when using list comprehension. @jezrael